# Parsing a data feed in python

Tags: python, function, parsing

I'm attempting to plot a live (and continuous) feed of data that is being dumped into a csv from another program. I got the plot working but then realized my data only plotted until the time I executed the code. I believe there is something wrong with my parse function (kind of new at this stuff) but I can't figure out what.

```
import threading
import csv 
import dateutil.parser 
import datetime
import time
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

log = "sample.csv"
data = ""
mytime = ""
thickness = ""
times = ""   

#attempt at continuously reading my data source 
def parser():
    with open(log, 'r') as f:
        global data
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')    
        data = reader.readlines()
        time_thickness_data = []
        while 1:
            last_pos = f.tell()
            next_line = f.readline()
            if not next_line:
                time.sleep(1)
                f.seek(last_pos)
            else:
                mytime, thickness = splitter(next_line)
                time_thickness_data.append([mytime, thickness])

def splitter(line):
    mytime = line[0]
    thickness = line[3]
    return (mytime, thickness)
    times = []
    for date in mytime: 
        _ = dateutil.parser.parse(date) 
        times.append(datetime.datetime.strftime(_,'%H')) 

def main():
    a = threading.Thread(target=parser)
    b = threading.Thread(target=splitter)
    a.start()
    b.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

#goes on to animated plot using times for x axis and thickness for y
fig = plt.figure()
axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
line, = axes.plot([], [], '.')
plt.show(block=False) #i had to use this to get my plot to show up

def init():
    line.set_data([],[]) 
    return line,

def animate(i):
    a = 50 * i
    xdata = times[:a]
    ydata = thickness[:a]
    line.set_data(xdata, ydata)
    plt.draw()
    axes.relim()
    axes.autoscale_view(True,True,True)
    return line,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,  
                           interval=1, blit=True)                           
plt.show()
```

Sample row from csv looks like this:
    `2015-07-25 14:54:50.786774,1,0,439.85,,,,0,0,`

Comment: can you pase some data?

Comment: Where is the plotting that you want to be continuously updated?

Comment: Well i was trying not to make this a monster post but I'll edit it back in.

Comment: Why are you using two threads reading same file before trying to process it with only one? What does this line `mytime, thickness = splitter(next_line)` does (1 param), when you declare `def splitter():` (0 param)?

Comment: @Serge Thats a good point, I attempted to fix that. I appreciate the feedback, I feel like I'm in over my head.

Comment: If anyone knows a simpler way to continuously read my data source, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too much unused pieces in your code to really understand what you were trying to achieve. Here is a simple function that:

- opens a csv file
- repeatedly read lines from it, waiting for new lines to be added when reaching end of file
- calls a callback function with the decoded list from each csv line

  ```
  def csv_process(filename, callback, delay=1):
      class waiter:     # wrapper around a file object to wait for new lines on EOF
          def __init__(self, fd, delay=1):
              self.fd = fd
              self.delay = delay
          def __iter__(self):
              return self
          def next(self):  # try to read a line of wait delay seconds
              while True:
                  line = fd.readline()
                  if line:
                      return line
                  time.sleep(self.delay)
          def __next__(self):  # ensure compatibility with Python3.x
              return self.next()
      with open(filename, "rb") as fd:
          rows = csv.reader(waiter(fd, delay), delimiter=',')
          for row in rows:
              callback(row)
  ```

Python2 iterators shall implement `next`, while Python3 ones shall implement `__next__`. To ensure compatibility with both, above code defines both methods.

Comment: Your code is far more compact than mine and I believe it accomplishes the same thing. I'm still trying to get it to work though. I defined filename and callback but when I run the code I get an error from the csv.reader stating that argument 1 must be an iterator. Is there something I need to do outside the function with the class you created?

Comment: @MBlankfield: what Python version are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 3.4

Comment: @MBlankfield: My iterator was only compatible with Python 2.x . I've updated my post to be compatible with Python 2.x and Python 3.x